# Laravel 5.1 : Testbench Install in Own Package instead of Main Application

Tags: php, laravel, testing, composer-php

I'm creating my own package in Laravel 5.1. My package has an own composer.json, in which I added:

```
"require-dev": {
    "orchestra/testbench": "~3.1"
}
```

When I do a composer install, Testbench requires a lot of dependencies (including Laravel **5.2**, see below the composer.json of the installed Testbench):

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.0",
    "laravel/framework": "~5.2.0",
    "orchestra/database": "~3.2.0",
    "symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
    "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*"
},
"require-dev": {
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0|~5.0"
}
```

It seems that Testbench has to be installed in de main installation. But then, I cannot deal with tests after publishing my package to for example Github.

So my thoughts are these:

- Install Testbench via global composer.json
- Install Testbench via my package composer.json, and after that: I remove the requirements (e.g. Laravel 5.2 requirement) and do an update
- I use the global phpunit instead of Testbench

I'm a little bit confused. How to use Testbench in my custom package without a sub installation of Laravel Framework and a lot of extra dependencies linked to Testbench?

Comment: For version **`3.1`** it seems Laravel dependency is **`~5.1.11`**. How did you get Laravel 5.2 as dependency?

Comment: You're right, but I simply do a 'composer install' from my package directory. After that, I see the vendor directory with a lot of packages, with Laravel 5.2 too.